# Como aplicar where dinamicamente mediante elocuent

Tags: php, laravel-8, where

me he topado con el siguiente requerimiento: necesito construir una consulta vía Elocuent que tiene que tener uno o mas orWhere concatenados dependiendo ciertos códigos de vendedores, les copio la consulta con la que estoy comenzando esto:

```
                $pedidos = Vta_PedidosVendedor_34::with('relUsers')->where('estado', '=', '0')->
                where('OrderNumber', 'like', '%' . $this->buscar . '%')->
                whereBetween('date', [$fd, $fd])-> 
                orderBy($this->orden, $this->direccion)->
                paginate(15);
```

Explico un poquito mas, cada usuario que ingresa al sistema tiene la capacidad de ver los pedidos de otros usuarios, por ejemplo si ingresa el usuario '34' puede ver sus pedidos + los del '15', '16' y '20', ahora bien, cuando cambia el usuario, por ejemplo ingresa el '40', este solo puede ver los pedidos del '11' y los suyos, cuyo id es '40'. Aquí es donde estoy trabado, no se como hacer para que esta consulta sea dinámica. En otros lenguajes (C#), lo que hacía era construir un select y mediante un array donde ponía los códigos que debían participar del select, lograba construir dinámicamente el select.
Esto mas o menos lo puedo reproducir utilizando directamente DB::, peeero, siempre hay un pero, esta construcción no me deja paginar, o al menos no se como hacerlo.

Desde ya, muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente funcion para crear una consulta dinamica dependiendo de lo que guardes en el array

```
//El 'use ($array)' es para poder utilizar dicha variable dentro de la funcion 
->where(function($query) use ($array){
//Valida si el array no esta vacio
                    if(!empty($array)){
//Si no esta vacio hago un foreach del array obtenido
                        foreach ($array as $cliente){
//Dentro del foreach hago un orWhere para que el foreach recorra todo el array
//Basicamente estaria haciendo orWhere('id','1')->orWhere('id','2') etc...
                        $query -> orWhere('id','=',$cliente);
                        }
                    }else{
//Si el array viene vacio, significa que (en mi caso) un administrador entro y por ende dicho array no tiene que llenarse porque el admin ve todo (esto es algo personal)
                        $query -> where ('id','0');
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Saludos.